"Kotlin Multiplatform Shared Module" Option Missing From "Create New Module" Dialog
Since updating Android Studio to Ladybug 2024.2.1 Patch 1 and Kotlin Multiplatform plugin to 0.8.3(242)-5, I'm seemingly no longer able to create a "Kotlin Multiplatform Shared Module" using the New Module Wizard (Create New Module dialog) as I'd previously been able to.
As mentioned, I'm currently using Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1 Patch 1, as per the following:

And Kotlin Multiplatform plugin version 0.8.3(242)-5, as shown below:

My "Create New Module" dialog appears as follows: (now lacking the "Kotlin Multiplatform Shared Module" option, at the bottom of the list on the left-hand side)

I can confirm that I've checked the "Enable experimental Multiplatform IDE features" checkbox, and restarted the IDE, as required.

I've tried using the File -> New -> New Module... method, shown below:

As well as the right-click project (in Project view) -> New -> Module method, shown here:

Both methods of accessing the "Create New Module" dialog yield identical results - no "Kotlin Multiplatform Shared Module" option.
I can confirm that when creating a new project using the "New Project" dialog, I can see the expected Kotlin Multiplatform project types (Kotlin Multiplatform App and Kotlin Multiplatform Library), without an issue:

I'm hopeful that I'm missing something obvious, though I suspect it's a bug. 
That said, if anyone has a fix, or neat workaround, it'd be greatly appreciated!
For the moment, I'm creating new modules by building out the directory structure manually (commonMain, etc. for each target), as well as the necessary build configuration (build.gradle.kts). This works fine, but isn't as quick as the IDE convenience had been. Another method that I'm occasionally using is to copy an existing Kotlin Multiplatform module and alter it appropriately.

Seems like android studio bug. I filed a bug report https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/376381176

This seems to actually be a problem with the latest version (0.8.3(242)-5) of the plugin.
You can download the previous version (0.8.3(242)-4) from the plugin versions  and manually install the plugin from disk in Android Studio.
